# vba not working with vlookup

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to write a document which automatically fires an email to certain people based on certain conditions. I have the code working, and am happy with what I have.

But....

When I change the email addresses on the worksheet into a vlookup, the coding I have no longer picks up the email addresses.

Is there any way that this can be fixed? Thanks in advance. Code as is, below.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim StrBody As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) 
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "true" Then 

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Urgent Training Notification  - Action Required"
            .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Please be aware, " & Cells(cell.Row, "D") & " is required to update the following training:" & vbNewLine & _
                    " " & vbNewLine & _
                    Cells(cell.Row, "E") & vbNewLine & _
                    " " & vbNewLine & _
                    "This must be rectified within 14 Days." & vbNewLine & _
                    " " & vbNewLine & _
                    " " & vbNewLine & _
                    "Any issues, please escalate as required." & vbNewLine & _
                    "Many thanks."

            .Send  'Or use Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the issue: For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).... You loop through Constant values while you use formula's. Why use specialcells anyway?

Comment: JvdV, I am new to VBA, so I adapted an example after much searching! When I remove the piece you mention, I seem to run into more issues. If I replace the '.To = ' to 'cell.row, "B").Value' again, nothing happens.

Comment: @MCheney copy-pasting code is one of the biggest disservices you can do to yourself. Not only there will almost always be something you need to adjust your own project accordingly, but you will miss out on most of the learning experience and even deeper understanding of how your program works. Creating issues like this, where you yourself have confusion in what the code is even supposed to really do. I personally would suggest starting over and writing it yourself from the scratch.

Comment: Thanks, I may well just do that as this clearly isn't working out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed with @Rawrplus, It really makes sense to try and understand the code. Anyway, if you are happy with your code then replace:

```
SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

with:

```
SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
```

As I said before, I wouldn't use SpecialCells but again, you are happy wit the code.

One more thing; do you have a formula in column C stating true or false? Then also remove the "true" and just type True in your code.

Good luck

Comment: Many thanks, this worked and solved the issue. Lesson learnt! I was using this as a basis to learn from, but I think you are all right in that going back to basics might be the better option. Thanks again.